CloudKit works on simulator but not on a real device
I'm developing an iOS 18 app that includes an inbox that allows me to send messages to all app users. I've used Private Database entries in my CloudKit to allow me to send the message to everyone and to track their individual read/unread and deleted status. In addition, the app also maintains specific data in the public database that is to be shared and updated by all users.
But capabilities work flawlessly on the iPhone 16 (iOS 18) simulator. When I load it into TestFlight or try to run it on my iPhone 15 Pro neither feature works.
When I setup debug message, it looks like everything works, but none of the database transaction are made and no error messages are generated.
I've tried all of the items I've been able to find on the internet thus far:

My Development database schema has been deployed to the Production database
My Signing & Capabilities are setup exactly the same for debug and release
I've added CloudKit.framework to Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content in the Target -> General tab
When I check the users iCloud availability it always returns with .available

Googling the problem does not return any new ideas and I seem to be at a dead end.
Update
I've continued to troubleshoot this issue over the last week and change.
My subscription does not register (cannot see it on production Subscriptions page on Cloudkit Console) and my fetch data (add(CKDatabaseOperation) returns no data.
Neither operation returns any error messages.
It's like the query finds no matches, but I've reviewed everything repeatedly and the field names are correct. All fields are indexed.
I've verified the Security Roles.
The whole thing works flawlessly on the simulator for development and production schemas, but does nothing with testing on a real device from Xcode or TestFlight.
Here is the source for my custom app delegate for my subscription and my class to fetch the mesages
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications
import CloudKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    @Published var isNotificationPresent: Bool = false
    @Published var notificationTapped: Bool = false
    
    var app: iLS_ToolkitApp?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        //application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        if getIcloudStatus() {
            // Request permission from user to send notification
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { authorized, error in
              if authorized {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                  application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                })
              }
                else {
                    print("Request Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Not Returned")")
                }
            })
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        } else {
            print("AppDeleagte iCloud not avaliable")
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        //Get Device ID for Testing
        let stringToken = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)}.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(stringToken)")
        
        let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "news", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), subscriptionID: "news_feed", options: .firesOnRecordCreation)
        
        let notification = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
        notification.titleLocalizationKey = "%1$@"
        notification.titleLocalizationArgs = ["title"]
        notification.alertLocalizationKey = "%1$@"
        notification.alertLocalizationArgs = ["message"]
        notification.soundName = "default"
        notification.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
        
        subscription.notificationInfo = notification
        
        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.save(subscription) { _, error in
            if let error {
                print("Subscription Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: Error) {
        print("Registration Failure \(Error.self)")
    }
}

extension AppDelegate {
    
    //Function is called when user taps the notification
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
        print("Notification Recieved")
        notificationTapped = true
    }
    
    //Function that is called when a Push notification is recieved
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification) async -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
        isNotificationPresent = true
        return [.banner, .list, .badge, .sound]
    }
    
    func getIcloudStatus() -> Bool {
        CKContainer.default().accountStatus { returnedStatus, returnedError in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch returnedStatus {
                case .available:
                    print("AppDelegate Cloudkit is available")
                default :
                    print("AppDelegate Cloudkit is not available")
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}

class CloudKitRecieveMessages: ObservableObject {
    @Published var processedMessages: [News] = []
    @Published var unreadCount: Int = 0
    @Published var totalCount: Int = 0
    
    init() {
        fetchNews()
    }
    
    func fetchNews() {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "news", predicate: predicate)
        //query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]
        
        let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        var tempNews: [News] = []
        
        //This property is defined before addOperation and data becomes available after
        //execution is async
        queryOperation.recordMatchedBlock = { returnedRecordId, returnedResult in
            print("in MatchBlock")
            switch returnedResult {
            case .success(let record):
                guard let title = record["title"] as? String else { print("title")
                    return }
                
                guard let message = record["message"] as? String else { print("message")
                    return }
                
                guard let deleted = record["deleted"] as? String else { print("deleted")
                    return }
                
                guard let unread = record["unread"] as? String else { print("unread")
                    return }
                
                guard let creation = record.creationDate else { print("creation")
                    return }
                
                tempNews.append(News(title: title, message: message, deleted: deleted, date: self.getDateFromCreationTime(d: creation), unRead: unread, record: record, creationDate: creation, time: self.getTimeFromCreationDate(d: creation)))
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("MatchedBlock Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        //This property is defined before addOperation and data becomes available after
        //execution is async
        queryOperation.queryResultBlock = { [weak self] returnedResult in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("result block: \(returnedResult) and \(tempNews)")
                self?.processedMessages.removeAll()
                self?.processedMessages.append(contentsOf: tempNews)
                self?.processedMessages.sort{
                    $0.creationDate < $1.creationDate
                }
                self?.getUnreadCount()
                self?.getTotalCount()
            }
        }
        addOperation(operation: queryOperation)
    }
    
    func addOperation(operation: CKDatabaseOperation) {
        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
    }
}


You stated "I've used Private Database entries in my CloudKit to allow me to send the message to everyone". This isn't possible. Each user has their own private database. You can't send data to other users via the private database.
